# Trouble capturing a return value from one method to another

Tags: java, oop, return, return-value

I am currently on creating a small application in Java. However, I am now stuck. I'm having trouble capturing a return value from one method to another.

Here is an example of when I return value and where I want to capture it:

```
public int[] highest(int y[]){
    int largest = 500;
    int largeArr[] = new int[y.length];
    for(int count = 0; count < y.length; count++)
    {        
        if(y[count] >= largest){
            largeArr[count] = y[count];
            System.out.print(largeArr[count] + " ");  
        }
    }
    return largeArr;
}

public void highText()
{
    RandomNumbers high = new RandomNumbers();
    System.out.println("\nDessa tal är " + high.highest() + " intervallet 500 - 999: ");
}
```

I am well aware that I should avail myself of parameters and arguments. But this becomes a problem for me when I want to print text at a later time

Entire code:

```
RandomNumbers rnd = new RandomNumbers();

        rnd.highText();
        rnd.highest(nummer);



import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomNumbers {
        public void rnd(int y[]){
            for(int count = 0; count < y.length; count++)
            {
                y[count] = (int) ( Math.random()*1000);
                System.out.print(y[count] + " ");
            }
        }

        public int[] lowest(int y[]){
            int largest = 499;
            int smallArr[] = new int[y.length];
            for(int count = 0; count < y.length; count++)
            {    
                if(y[count] <= largest){
                    smallArr[count] = y[count];
                    System.out.print(smallArr[count] + " ");
                }
            }
            return smallArr;
        }

        public int[] highest(int y[]){
            int largest = 500;
            int largeArr[] = new int[y.length];
            for(int count = 0; count < y.length; count++)
            {        
                if(y[count] >= largest){
                    largeArr[count] = y[count];
                    System.out.print(largeArr[count] + " ");  
                }
            }
            return largeArr;
        }

        public void highText()
        {
            RandomNumbers high = new RandomNumbers();
            System.out.println("\nDessa tal är " + high.highest() + " intervallet 500 - 999: ");
        }
        public void lowText()
        {
            System.out.println("\nDessa " + smallArr + " tal är i intervallet 0 - 499: ");
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Hur många slumptal i intervallet 0-999 önskas? ");
        int x = user_input.nextInt();
        int nummer[] = new int[x];

        RandomNumbers rnd = new RandomNumbers();

        System.out.println("\nHär är de slumpade talen: ");
        rnd.rnd(nummer);

        rnd.lowText();
        rnd.lowest(nummer);

        rnd.highText();
        rnd.highest(nummer);
     }

}
```

When I print the text, I use the method rnd.highText ();. If I previously am using largeArr in parameters, so the program requests argument - when I really just want to print the method: (

Please help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you want but...
If you want to wrote from method old value that you already calculated you must save it into global varible or somehow other way that you would have access to her from outside the method. The for just writing the result you have two options. You can pass as argument when you call method null and just check argument if is null you write the old result if you have it (you should have it). 
So the call would be:

rnd.highText(null);

And the changed method would be:

```
 int largeArr[];
    public int[] highest(int y[]){
                if(y!=null)
                {
                    int largest = 500;
                    largeArr[] = new int[y.length];
                    for(int count = 0; count < y.length; count++)
                    {        
                        if(y[count] >= largest){
                            largeArr[count] = y[count];
                            System.out.print(largeArr[count] + " ");  
                        }
                    }
                }
                return largeArr;
            }
```

Another way to acomplish this is to create another method (with same name) which don't take non argument. But just write saved version of highest or lovest elements. In each case you need to keep result in some varible, because now after end of method you lose the result and is no way to get it back unles you call method agan. I hope that you understand what I'm trying to tell you.